# Tornado POST request not working

Tags: python, post, tornado

I've taken the below code from the Tornado server documentation and attempted to try it out but instead I keep getting the error

> object has no attribute 'get_body_argument'

```
class MyFormHandler(RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.write('<html><body><form action="/myform" method="POST">'
               '<input type="text" name="message">'
               '<input type="submit" value="Submit">'
               '</form></body></html>')

def post(self):
    self.set_header("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    self.write("You wrote " + self.get_body_argument("message"))
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What version of tornado are you using?

Comment: Turns out I was using an old version, and after upgrading to the newest version it now works! thanks!

Comment: Just to be a little more specific, this does not seem to work in tornado 3.1, even though it's mentioned in the [docs](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/branch3.1/web.html). It works in the current version (4.1)

Answer (score 0):

All it needed was my installation of Tornado had to be upgraded.